# CakePHP: Vendor file can't see variables set before it was loaded

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I am trying to pass a variable to a vendor file like so:

```
    echo '>'.$foo;
    App::import('Vendor', 'foo'.DS.'bar');
```

Inside my vendor file I also have `echo '>'.$foo;`

The first time before I load the vendor file it echos $foo just fine. The second time inside the vendor file it tells me $foo is not defined.

How can I pass the variable to the vendor file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't you expect this behaviour?

This is because your `$foo` variable is not defined inside the `App::import()` method, which calls the PHP `include` statement.

```
$defined = 'fooBar'; // define
foo(); // call foo()

function foo()
{
  echo $defined; // undefined
  bar();
}

function bar()
{
  echo $defined; // undefined
}
```

How about just using `include` directly? Or creating a class in the file you're including and instantiating it?

Comment: Sorry, I just read this over, I don't mean to sound condescending! I'm probably totally wrong on this.

Comment: This.makes sense. I was expecting it to work like it would if I did just use include but I wasn't considering the scope of the import function call itself. Currently I was just using $GLOBALS to get around this. Thanks.